# is it possible to get connected on my server through SSH, while the server is connected to a VPN?

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, vpn

I've a server with Debian 8 on it, and a VPN connected to free vpnbook for the moment.

The problem is that, when I launch the connection to the VPN with openvpn, I'm not able to access to my server anymore, nor from SSH, nor my websites on it. Which is normal, because all the traffic is going through the VPN.

So, I would like to know, if it is possible to get connected on my server through SSH, while the server is connected to a VPN ?

Comment: You want a specific route for your server so that the packets will take the route through your standard interface instead of the TAP/TUN one.

Comment: The VPN may be installing firewall policies @phk as per the standard in the industry... He would need to reach it from the Internet, for instance.

Comment: Well I found this : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237460/ssh-into-a-server-which-is-connected-to-a-vpn-service

But it didn't change anything, I still cannot connect through SSH..