# OpenVPN - Keep local routes

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I've setup OpenVPN on my Ubuntu (16.04 / OpenVPN 2.4) box to start at boot. This work in the sense that a connection gets established, but unfortunately it also seems to mess with my routing tables: I am unable to reach the box once the VPN connection is up.

My first attempt was adding another NIC to have a dedicated VPN-NIC, but as far as I can tell this isn't really an option with OpenVPN. I've also tried following [this guide](https://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/) for setting up policy routing, but to no effect.

My last attempt so far was adding routes for local ranges in the config -file, but as far as I've understood it this is supposed to be used "in reverse" (adding routes for traffic you want redirected, not excluded).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found a workable solution here, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243033. Adding the suggested rules directly to /etc/network/interfaces. However I'm still interested in understanding if this can be done with OpenVPN configuration only.