# ssh into a server which is connected to a VPN service, using ifconfig and route not ip

Tags: networking, ip, openbsd, route, ifconfig

Same issue as described here:
[ssh into a server which is connected to a VPN service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237460/ssh-into-a-server-which-is-connected-to-a-vpn-service)

However I have no access to the "ip" utility. Just good 'ol ifconfig and route commands as I'm working on an OpenBSD box. How would one do the same task with those commands?

Trying to translate the following commands to ifconfig & route:

`ip rule add table 128 from 50.1.2.3`

`ip route add table 128 to 50.1.2.0/24 dev eth0`

`ip route add table 128 default via 50.1.2.1`

So far ive roughly translated the last two commands to

`route add [128] $PUBLICSUBNET/24 vio0`

`route add [128] $PUBLICSUBNET/24 vio0`

but still stuck on the first one.

Comment: Please describe your problem instead of linking to a different question. Which `ip` commands do you want to replace by `ifconfig` and `route`?

Comment: `ip rule add table 128 from 50.1.2.3`

`ip route add table 128 to 50.1.2.0/24 dev eth0`

`ip route add table 128 default via 50.1.2.1`